# Tesseract OCR.init() makes the code to exit in Sharepoint website

Tags: sharepoint, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

We are using Tesseract OCR (tessnet2 dll) for converting image to text which is working fine in Console Application. But, when we host the same in sharepoint, the application exits at ocr.init(). In few posts, it is mentioned that the tessdata folder should be under bin/debug. But, for sharepoint site, where I need to keep tessdata folder?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with tessnet2 wrapper, but tesseract API allows you to [specify datapath](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/048f729785c84c750ecf637e1bd143a8b4abd537/src/api/baseapi.h#L220) (there are relevant call also in [C-API](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/048f729785c84c750ecf637e1bd143a8b4abd537/src/api/capi.h#L286)).

Tesseract wrote error message to console, so it would be useful to catch error reason. You can try to set variable `debug_file` to redirect it to file, but I am not sure if it will be working before init...